# trying to create a trigger that updates the quantity of one table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables for products that are being sold. One is the table for the actual products and the other is for the ordered item.

The ordered item table records the itemId and quantity sold.

I want to create a trigger that takes the data from the ordered item table and update the product table quantity which the column is called quantityInStock.

this is the trigger that I wrote but I keep getting an error:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger stockUpdate 
after insert on orderItem 
for each row  
 begin  
  update item(quantityInStock)  
  set quantityInStock = quantityInStock - orderItem.quantity    
  where itemId = orderItem.itemId; 
 end$$
```

my error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(quantityInStock)
>   set quantityInStock = quantityInStock - orderItem.quantity w' at line 5

Comment: @Quanlong  thank you. still learning how to use this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your update syntax.

```
update table_name
set column_name = ...
where column_name = ...;
```

You can reference the previous/new row values with `old.column_name`, `new.column_name` respectively.

Some things to consider:

How to prevent quantity from going negative

Comment: Thank you. I removed the (quantityInStock) from the updated and added "new." and it worked.